# Prelaod fetches multiple times

Tags: html, css, preload

In the example below im calling the preload tag mechanism to fetch some resources ahead of time. Doing so, preload  fetched the css resource multiple times? Why is this happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

      <link rel="preload" onload="console.log('script')"  as="script" href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'>
      <link rel="preload" onload="this.rel = 'stylesheet'; console.log('css')"  as="style" href='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/welcome.b2b.test/form/bundle.css'>


    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        console.log("window");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should not do that. If I paste your html in jsfiddle it only loads it once (using chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/9mbL45r6/. what browser are you using, preload isn't supported by a lot of browser right now.

Comment: @Merijndk see updated question

Comment: Wierd, can you try the jsfiddle and see if it loads multiple overthere aswell?

Comment: @Merijndk i have cache disabled  but again it doesnt explain this.